# Librdkafka | Error: Invalid value "sasl_ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol"

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, macos-catalina, librdkafka

I'm new to kafka, trying to explore it on my mac Catalina. I've gone through documentation and few forum but no luck in running it.

I followed the below steps:

1. Installed openssl@1.1 with brew.
2. `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
3. `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"`
4. `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"`
5. Then installed librdkafka.
6. Made a producer service and I'm unable to run it.

It keeps throwing me the

```
Error: Invalid value "sasl_ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol".
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install librdkafka? From source or through homebrew? The latter is recommended.

Comment: Using homebrew @Edenhill